# Can I set default store view label using my attribute script in magento

Tags: php, magento, entity-attribute-value

I am using a module to create a new attribute on the customer model. Does anyone know how to set the default store view using my setup script?

[image: admin screenshot]

My current script:

```
$setup = new Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Setup('customer_setup');

if (! $setup->getAttribute('customer', 'dob_month')) {
    $setup->addAttribute('customer', 'dob_month', array(
        'label'     => 'Month',
        'type'      => 'varchar',
        'input'     => 'select',
        'source'    => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_table',
        'required'  => true,
        'position'  => 1,
        'option'    => array (
            'values' => array (
                'January',
                'February',
                'March',
                'April',
                'May',
                'June',
                'July',
                'August',
                'September',
                'October',
                'November',
                'December'
            )
        )
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know it is impossible to do this directly in the `addAttribute()` call. But you can set store labels after saving attribute in the next way:

```
$attributeId = $this->getAttributeId('customer', 'dob_month');
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->load($attributeId);
$attribute->setStoreLabels(array(store_id => 'Store label'))
    ->save();
```

Comment: Works very well. The first and second can also be replaced by just `$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('customer', 'dob_month');`

Comment: Also note that this doesn't work for the default (store id: 0) store view. For that you need to use setFrontendLabel like so: `$attribute->setFrontendLabel('Test')->setStoreLabels(array(1 => 'Test Again'))->save();`

Comment: @Alex, can you provide the fix for m2 as well. I am facing same issue here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/253672/update-attribute-option-label-with-id-magento2